# How to specify day of year in QDateTimeEdit display format?

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can I use the day of year in the QDateTimeEdit display format? I know I can specify the display format using the displayFormat method, but the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdate.html#toString) doesn't show a way to use day of year formating. Ex. 29-July-2023 would be 2023-210.

All the data that that I am using uses ordinal dates to keep track of information. As such it is easiest to be able to input an ordinal date rather than converting it and then inputting it.

My current solution uses a line edit with an input mask and a validator method, but I was wondering if there was a more robust solution.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class DateEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.validate)
        self.setPlaceholderText('yyyy-ddd')
    
    def validate(self):
        print(self.cursorPosition())
        text = self.text()
        print(text.split('-'))
        if len(text) > 5 and int(text.split('-')[1]) > 366:
            self.setText(text[:-1])
                
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if self.text() == '':
            self.setInputMask('9999-900')
    
    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if self.text() == '-':
            self.setInputMask('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QWidget()
    main.setFixedSize(200, 100)
    edit1 = DateEdit()
    edit2 = DateEdit()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(edit1)
    layout.addWidget(edit2)
    main.setLayout(layout)
    main.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: QDateTimeEdit (and its inherited QDateEdit/QTimeEdit subclasses) is weird. It probably is one of the most logically inconsistent widgets in the Qt library, but that is understandable, as display and management of date/times is incredibly difficult. Also, user edit of spinboxes is extremely complex; QDateTimeEdit inherits from QAbstractSpinBox, and that inheritance includes some known editing issues related to keyboard input: consider how should be interpreted a typed "1" in a range between 9 and 11. This is probably doable, but requires some proper research.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're eligible of offering a [SO:faq:#bounty]. With your current reputation, that would be a relatively high cost, but it may be worth the effort. As far as I understand, there are possible solutions to your questions, but they require proper research and efforts (I know, as I did some simple tests); a bounty would certainly attract more attention, and the reputation points gained from it may be increased even further from. Further improvements would be achieved if you added your own attempts in solving this problem (by [edit]ing your question), even if they failed.

Comment: Is it really worth bothering with QDateTimeEdit? The equivalent functionality can be very easily achieved using two spin-boxes (or maybe combo-boxes) for the year and day-number. I've always thought that the main use-case for the rather finicky QDate/TimeEdit classes is that they can *display dates and times in a familiar format*. But day-number/year definitely doesn't fall into that category - in fact, from a user POV, 210-2023 looks quite unintuitive to me. What is the context for this? How exactly would the widget be used in your application?

Comment: I agree with @ekhumoro: I have no issue with using the ordinal date format from ISO 8601(which `210-2023` is **not** but `2023-210` would be); however, even if a human being can somewhat figure out the month and day from the ordinal format, this is defined primarily for systems to exchange information between one another, not for display on screen. As such, could you help us understand the context of your question, that is why you want it shown to user?

Comment: @ekhumoro I have edited my answer to provide some more information.

Comment: @Jake_the_camper Your edits don't really explain much. Why does ***the user*** need to input ordinal dates? Why not input calendar dates and then convert them programmatically for internal use? What is the purpose of ***displaying*** ordinal dates, given that most users usually won't know which calendar date they refer to?

Comment: @ekhumoro I've seen some cases of such formats, often used in accounting (some programs/spreadsheets and even paper documentation). From what I can understand, the OP probably has to work with such kind of format from another source that cannot be programmatically accessed, which would probably make it easier to them (or the end users) to directly input instead of making the conversion, no matter how "unreadable" that format is.

Comment: @Jake_the_camper At least for the sake of knowledge (but also to know if, maybe, other solutions may be used), can you explain what is "all the data [you are] using"? Do you have to manually input dates written in such format from another source (paper, spreadsheet, etc) that you cannot programmatically use/insert from the program? Or is it related to a database field that only uses ordinal numbers for dates of a specific year? If that's the case, why don't you just do the conversion to actual QDate (through `addDays()`) and show it in a standard QDateEdit?

Comment: @musicamante No one is denying such a format has legitimate uses (after all, QDate provides support for it via several APIs). But the OPs question still lacks essential details about exactly how the user is supposed to interact with the interface. It seems from the lastest edit that the question has more to do with *validation* (e.g, from copy-paste) than with *manual input* (e.g. composing an arbitrary ordinal date). But without knowing the full context, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @ekhumoro The data that the user is referencing comes from text and csv files which use ordinal dates.  Based on information from these file the user selects a start and end date and inputs them into the gui. These dates are then passed to another script with only accepts ordinal dates. My goal is to have a way for the user to input dates they already have and pass those directly to the script rather than having to convert the date from an ordinal to a typical calendar format, input that into the gui, and then convert it back to an ordinal to be passed to the script.

Comment: @Jake_the_camper So, you don't really need a QDateEdit, but, as ekhumoro wrote, a validation, which would be much more simple to implement (basic QLineEdit+QValidator) than going through all the implementation of a QDateEdit subclass. Writing a fully valid regex might be challenging for dates, so subclassing QValidator and just doing basic string manipulation would be much easier: it would just be a matter of something like `if '/' in text:` `day, year = text.split('/')` `valid = (day.isdigit() and 0 < int(day) <= 366) and (year.isdigit() and 1970 <= int(year) < 2100`.

Comment: An additional check for the QValidator approach might be to use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) with the `%Y` and `%j` format codes. This will deal neatly with non-leap year cases like `2023-366` (which resolves to `2024-001`). Personally, I would avoid using an input mask, as it's far too limiting - ideally, the validator should be as tolerant as possible and allow pretty much any input than can be parsed using the above codes to a Python `date` object. Once you have that, it can be normalised to whatever format you like.

Comment: The tricky thing with the QValidator approach is deciding how to deal with *partial* input. When typing input character by character, the validator must allow values that could *eventually* form part of a valid ordinal date. A regexp might work well for this, if it was combined with `strptime`. The idea would be to first match a string that was suitable to feed to `strptime`, and then use that to validate/fixup the final value.

Comment: @Jake_the_camper What exactly does "select" and "input" mean in your above comment? Is the user copy-pasting *whole values*, or do they need to compose new values from scratch? I  suspect there may be much simpler solutions available here, but your descriptions are still too vague to be sure. If you already have initial data taken from text/csv files, why can't you just use that to provide the min/max values of some spin-boxes? It's really not at all clear why the user needs to deal with raw textual input.

Comment: @ekhumoro The user needs to make a judgement on which range of dates best fits their goal given the information in certain documents. Once this decision has been made then they type their dates into this portion of the gui. Copying and pasting would be a nice feature, but 90% of the time the dates will be hand typed. Most of the documents themselves are on a separate system and cannot be accessed by the gui, though for those that are on the same system the user may wish to copy and paste the date instead of typing it. My reasoning for using an input mask was to fill in the '-' automatically.

Comment: @Jake_the_camper Given your last comment, it seems two spin-boxes would be the simplest solution. That allows the user to enter the dates via typing, copy-paste, arrow/page keys, mouse-wheel, or up/down buttons. There's no input validation required, because the min/max values constrain the values. Functionally, this is almost identical to a date-edit - except it's not integrated into a single widget. If you really can't live with this last point, I suppose a line-edit with a validator is the next best solution - but that entails quite a lot of extra work for just a minor cosmetic gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the current **QDateEdit** to have a different behavior for displaying and inputting the text, while still maintaining the functionality of **QDateEdit** (such as the popup and context menu). The current date format is now in the form of ordinal date (e.g. `2020/123`).

* *As **@musicamante** mentioned, I changed the displayFormat back to `yyyy/ddd`.
I also added a separator variable to easily change the separator.
There is also an issue with the `currentSection` which I think can be fixed by re-implementing the `onKeyPressEvent`.*

To achieve this, I looked into the [Qt source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdatetimeedit.cpp.html) and Qt documentation, and after some trial and error, I found that the following functions needed to be reimplemented:

- `dateTimeFromText(text)` [[1](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.dateTimeFromText)]: For parsing input in the ordinal date format.
- `textFromDateTime(dt)` [[2](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.textFromDateTime)]: For displaying the ordinal date in the proper format.
- `validate(text, pos)` [[3](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAbstractSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.validate)]: Changing the validation based on the ordinal date format.
- `stepBy(steps)` [[4](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAbstractSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.stepBy)] and `stepEnabled()` [[5](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAbstractSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.stepEnabled)]: These two functions are also reimplemented to fix a limitation when modifying days using arrow keys.

The code seems to work correctly in my testing, but there may be some errors. I haven't tested it for locale changes either, but it should provide a good starting point.
Also, I'm not really a Python programmer, so the code may not adhere to best practices.

```py
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtGui import QValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QDateEdit

class CustomDateEdit(QDateEdit):
    def __init__(self, separator = '/'):
        super().__init__()
        self.separator = separator
        self.setDisplayFormat('yyyy{0}ddd'.format(self.separator))

    def dateTimeFromText(self, text: str | None) -> QDateTime:
        try:
            year_str, day_str = text.split(self.separator)
            day, year = int(day_str), int(year_str)
        except:
            year, day = 1, 1

        date = QDateTime(QDate(year, 1, 1).addDays(day - 1))
        date.setTime(self.time())

        return QDateTime(date)

    def textFromDateTime(self, dt: QDateTime | datetime) -> str:
        year = dt.date().year()
        day = dt.date().dayOfYear()
        return "{0}{1}{2:0>3}".format(year, self.separator, day)

    def stepBy(self, steps: int) -> None:
        if self.currentSection() == QDateEdit.Section.DaySection:
            date = self.date()
            leap = QDate().isLeapYear(date.year())
            if date.dayOfYear() + steps <= (365 + int(leap)):
                self.setDate(date.addDays(steps))
        else:
            super().stepBy(steps)

    def stepEnabled(self) -> QDateEdit.StepEnabled:
        if self.currentSection() == QDateEdit.Section.DaySection:
            date = self.date()
            leap = QDate().isLeapYear(date.year())
            flag = QDateEdit.StepEnabledFlag.StepNone

            if date.dayOfYear() < (365 + int(leap)):
                flag = QDateEdit.StepEnabledFlag.StepUpEnabled
            if 1 < date.dayOfYear():
                flag |= QDateEdit.StepEnabledFlag.StepDownEnabled

            return flag
        else:
            return super().stepEnabled()

    def validate(self, input: str | None, pos: int):
        try:
            year_str, day_str = input.split(self.separator)
            day, year = int(day_str), int(year_str)
        except:
            year, day = 1, 1

        new_date = QDate(year, 1, 1).addDays(day - 1)
        is_leap = new_date.isLeapYear(year)

        have_slash = input.count(self.separator) == 1
        range_valid = self.minimumDate() < new_date and new_date < self.maximumDate()
        day_in_range = day < (365 + int(is_leap))

        if have_slash and day_in_range and range_valid:
            state = QValidator.State.Acceptable
        elif have_slash and year_str and len(year_str) < 4:
            state = QValidator.State.Intermediate
        else:
            state = QValidator.State.Invalid

        return (state, input, pos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QWidget()
    cdate_edit = CustomDateEdit()
    cdate_edit.setCalendarPopup(True)
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(cdate_edit)
    main.setLayout(layout)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This seems promising, but has two issues: 1. the OP asked to use the format `d/yyyy`, while your approach uses the opposite (possibly for convenience, since putting the day first creates issue in editing); 2. the 364 used for comparison is wrong, it should be 365.

Comment: Thanks, @musicamante. I fixed the issues you mentioned. But what I see in the question is the `2023-210` format. However, I didn't actually follow all the comments, as they are unreasonably long. Currently, I swapped it to `ddd/yyyy` format, but if the OP asks, I can swap it back.

Comment: Gosh, you're right, sorry. The OP changed that aspect, they originally used `ddd-yyyy` in the first version of the question, and I missed that update.

Comment: I've seen your update, and I'd suggest to add a warning about changing the order, because due to the dynamic length of the day "field" putting it as first complicates things when the cursor has reached the second digit of the day: QDateTimeEdit automatically skips to the next section when it "believes" that editing of that section may have been completed, and since the day section normally only has up to two digits, that is a problem when trying to type 3-digits day numbers, because once the second digit has been typed it will automatically skip to the year section.

Comment: This is also an issue when the mouse cursor is moved to the end of a 3-digit day number, as `stepEnabled` and `stepBy` won't work properly, because they automatically assume the current section only based on the display format, not the current contents of the line edit; the result is that `stepEnabled` may show invalid arrows and `stepBy` will update the wrong section, because it believes that the `YearSection` is the current one. Finally, if I may, I suggest you to change all links to the official Qt C++ API instead of the PySide one, which is known to be unreliable and inconsistent.